# How switch view after making an AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I can't switch my view after sending an AJAX POST request from the view.

```js
$("._button2").click(function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); // Find the row
  var model = {
    IDLicence: $row.find(".IDLicence").text(),
    name: $row.find(".name").text(),
    tel_number: $row.find(".name").text(),
    seniority: $row.find(".seniority").text(),
    eye_examination: $row.find(".eye_examination").text()
  };

  var url = "@Url.Action("Edit","Ctaxi")";
  $.post(url, model)
});
```

This is my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Driver d)
{
  return View("Edit");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'switch view'? Do you want to stay on the current page and update the HTML within it, or redirect to another URL?

Comment: Keeping in mind, one of the primary reasons to use ajax is to avoid page transfers.

Comment: `var url = "@Ur.Actionl..." + "?" + $.param(model); location.href = url`

Comment: You can't post to an action and redirect to the view that's returned in a single step (you probably can, but with a lot of messing about).  The normal process is **post-redirect-get** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) - ie you post to your edit action, then the edit action returns a url that your `$.post` callback redirects to.  Yes, it means two calls, but it keeps the responsibilities in the correct place (1 action to handle a post/save, 1 action to handle drawing the saved values).

Comment: In this case, it's unclear what you're returning with `View("Edit")` - it looks like it would be an edit form, passing in the details - in that case you don't want your `Edit(Driver d)` to be `[HttpPost]` and you should do a GET (or simple redirect) to the edit action, *then* have a Post equivalent that the form makes the save to - ie one action draws the edit form, the other accepts) - they can have the same name if they have different parameters and one has `[HttpPost]`